# How to prevent Firefox from expanding flex items when they contain a 100% max-width/height image?

Tags: css, firefox, flexbox

I have a flexbox container with two items. In each item, there is an image with max-width: 100% and max-height: 100%
Firefox expands the items, so that they fill the entire container, as if I had set "flex: auto" or "flex-grow: 1" to the items :

[image: Firefox]

I would like to have the same behaviour than in Chrome :
[image: Chrome]

Is it possible ?

```css
.container {
    height: 400px;
    display: flex;

}
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div style="background-color:gainsboro">
        <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/900×700/?fruit" alt="">
    </div>
    <div style="background-color: chocolate;">
        <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/900×700/?flower" alt="">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You're missing a height definition on the `img` containers. Percentage heights require a specified height on the parent, or they default to `height: auto` (content-based). Chrome seems to be deviating from the spec in order to cover for code that overlooks this rule. FF adheres to the rule. https://jsfiddle.net/fdLztq95/

Comment: [Working with the CSS `height` property and percentage values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31728799/3597276).

Comment: Thank you!
I thought that the img container, as a flex item (with align-items: stretch), had automatically the same height as its parent.
Unfortunately, the real case I am working on is not as simple as the example I attached here, and I am still struggling to set a height property, but it is a good start, thank you.